# The system cannot find the batch label specified

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Currently i am running this file it is showing me error that

**The system cannot find the batch label specified - Begin_bealelaw**

I am stuck in this issue right now this error never happened before.

the file content is

```
cd\ 
D:
cd D:\Autodeployment
cd MultipleDeployment
cd Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046
@echo off

  echo stopping_Tomcat7-28
  sc stop Tomcat7-28 >D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/Tomcat7-28.log
  echo tomcat stopping start at
  TIME /T
  if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto waitForTomcat
  if %errorlevel% EQU 1062 goto mainProcessStart

  :waitForTomcat
  echo waitForTomcat
  @find /i "stopped successfully" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/Tomcat7-28.log"
  if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto scCheckRunning

  :scCheckRunning
  echo scCheckRunning
  sc query "Tomcat7-28" >D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/Tomcat7-28.log
  if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto scCheckStopped

  :scCheckStopped
  echo scCheckStopped
  @find /i "STOPPED" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/Tomcat7-28.log"
  if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto mainProcessStart
  if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto scCheckRunning

  :mainProcessStart
  echo tomcat stopping end at
  TIME /T
  echo mainProcessStart

start /B call D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/bealelaw.bat 1>D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/bealelaw.log 2>&1

start /B call D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/debrauw.bat 1>D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/debrauw.log 2>&1

start /B call D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/lexence.bat 1>D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/lexence.log 2>&1

start /B call D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/osborneclarke.bat 1>D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/osborneclarke.log 2>&1

start /B call D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/rl.bat 1>D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/rl.log 2>&1

start /B call D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/trowers.bat 1>D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/trowers.log 2>&1

start /B call D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/dahl.bat 1>D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/dahl.log 2>&1


    echo bealelaw_Build
    :Begin_bealelaw
    @find /i "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/bealelaw.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_debrauw
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto BUILD_FAILED_bealelaw

    :BUILD_FAILED_bealelaw
    @find /i "BUILD FAILED" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/bealelaw.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_debrauw
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto Begin_bealelaw 

    echo debrauw_Build
    :Begin_debrauw
    @find /i "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/debrauw.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_lexence
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto BUILD_FAILED_debrauw

    :BUILD_FAILED_debrauw
    @find /i "BUILD FAILED" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/debrauw.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_lexence
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto Begin_debrauw 

    echo lexence_Build
    :Begin_lexence
    @find /i "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/lexence.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_osborneclarke
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto BUILD_FAILED_lexence

    :BUILD_FAILED_lexence
    @find /i "BUILD FAILED" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/lexence.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_osborneclarke
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto Begin_lexence 

    echo osborneclarke_Build
    :Begin_osborneclarke
    @find /i "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/osborneclarke.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_rl
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto BUILD_FAILED_osborneclarke

    :BUILD_FAILED_osborneclarke
    @find /i "BUILD FAILED" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/osborneclarke.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_rl
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto Begin_osborneclarke 

    echo rl_Build
    :Begin_rl
    @find /i "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/rl.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_trowers
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto BUILD_FAILED_rl

    :BUILD_FAILED_rl
    @find /i "BUILD FAILED" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/rl.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_trowers
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto Begin_rl 

    echo trowers_Build
    :Begin_trowers
    @find /i "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/trowers.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_dahl
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto BUILD_FAILED_trowers

    :BUILD_FAILED_trowers
    @find /i "BUILD FAILED" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/trowers.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto Begin_dahl
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto Begin_trowers 

    echo dahl_Build
    :Begin_dahl
    @find /i "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/dahl.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto start_Tomcat7-28
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto BUILD_FAILED_dahl

    :BUILD_FAILED_dahl
    @find /i "BUILD FAILED" "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/dahl.log"
    if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto start_Tomcat7-28
    if %errorlevel% EQU 1 goto Begin_dahl 

  :start_Tomcat7-28
  echo starting_Tomcat7-28
  echo Please start Tomcat7-28
  net start Tomcat7-28

  exit
```

---

The ...bealelaw bat as posted in reply to query:

```
cd\ D:
cd Projects 
cd Collaborate 
cd Branches 
cd R3_1_3 
cd deployment 
call ant autoUpgrade_with_Batch -noinput -Dproperty.file=D:\Projects\properties\Collaborate\collabdev1\prod.properties -Dversion="3.1.3 app10.dev t7-28" -DstartLableName=3.1.3 -DendLableName=3.1.3 -DdryRunLable=y 
exit
```

Comment: You are starting 7 batch files inside the same console, SHARING the same console, without waiting for them to end. Are you sure the error is from this batch file and not from one of the others?

Comment: Having nothing to do with the direct question, there are significant logic problems throughout. For example, the :waitForTomcat section always falls through to :scCheckRunning, regardless the result of the FIND.

Comment: @dbenham ohh!! i had forgot to change it.

Comment: @MCND yes this error occurred in this file.

Answer (score 1):

If this log file

```
 "D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/bealelaw.log"
```

doesn't contain `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` or `BUILD FAILED` then that is the only time that

```
goto Begin_bealelaw
```

will be executed, and it will go into an endless loop.

Comment: How can a stack overflow be generated from a `:label / goto label`?

Comment: That's a good question.  I wish I had a good answer, but there are two sets of `goto` commands involved.  If I were really keen I'd set up the situation and test it,

Comment: Done, similar situation, batch in background generating data, two labels, two gotos, iterating using find, 1000000 iterations. Boring, but it does not fail.

Comment: Yes, I've been running it for 23 minutes too, no issues.  I can't think of a reason for the `missing label` error.

Comment: i have to wait for tomcat to stop and it takes 1 or more minutes to stop so i had made changes to check tomcat has stopped or not and print its status in tomcat7-28.log file from STOP-PENDING to STOPPED,So can it possible that "tomcat7-28.log" log overflowing stack?

Comment: The log has no connection to the stack, and log filesize is only limited in FAT32 (to 4gb).  if you want to delay while tomcat is stopping then use `timeout /t 60 /nobreak` for 60 seconds or `ping -n 60 localhost>nul` if your Windows doesn't have timeout.

Answer (score 0):

ISTM this batch is being dynamically created rather than supplying appropriate parameters (like the date string required, for instance).

Are you sure that the creating process has completed and closed the file before it is invoked?

Comment: yes i've created this file dynamically and yes first i create this file and than run via scheduler it will run after some time.

Comment: Could you please post a listing of `D:\Autodeployment/MultipleDeployment/Tomcat7-28_app4.sg1_18_01_2014_102046/bealelaw.bat` - I can only conclude that the errant label is expected in but missing from *that* batch.

Comment: cd\
D:
cd Projects
cd Collaborate
cd Branches
cd R3_1_3
cd deployment
call ant autoUpgrade_with_Batch -noinput -Dproperty.file=D:\Projects\properties\Collaborate\collabdev1\prod.properties -Dversion="3.1.3 app10.dev t7-28" -DstartLableName=3.1.3 -DendLableName=3.1.3 -DdryRunLable=y
exit